# numpy loadtxt ValueError: invalid literal for float()

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as n

a=n.loadtxt("data.txt",dtype=[('ID',int),('ID2',int),('ID3',int),
                              ('GENDER','|S1'),('ID4',int),('ID5',int)])

print len(n.unique(a[a['GENDER']==f]['ID']))
```

I have problem with this code,I was trying to count how many womans I have in my data file,so I used numpy .loadtxt and .unique but I've got strange (for me) error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\xy\bazy.py", line 78, in <module>
a=n.loadtxt("C:\\Users\\DzwiedzN7\\Desktop\\plec.txt",dtype=[('ID',int),('U-  ID',int),('KIER',int),('PLEC','|S1'),('TRYB',int),('RODZAJ',int)])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 848, in loadtxt
items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 616, in <lambda>
return lambda x: int(float(x))
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0,6288,10,f,3,4
```

I don't get it,what is about this iteral for float?There is no float and it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default delimiter of `loadtxt` is whitespace.  You want to use a comma, so add the argument `delimiter=','` to the `loadtxt` call.

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.loadtxt(file_,dtype=object)`

OR

Open your file as a dataframe and convert it to a numpy array

```
import pandas as pd
print pd.read_csv(file_).as_matrix()
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it is trying to convert `'0,6288,10,f,3,4'` indicates that you have a delimiter error as `Warren` points out.

As to why it is complaining about a float when all of your dtypes are int., a clue can be found in `lambda x: int(float(x))`.

The code to select default converters is (from np.lib/npyio.py):

```
def _getconv(dtype):
    typ = dtype.type
    if issubclass(typ, np.bool_):
        return lambda x: bool(int(x))
    if issubclass(typ, np.uint64):
        return np.uint64
    if issubclass(typ, np.int64):
        return np.int64
    if issubclass(typ, np.integer):
        return lambda x: int(float(x))
    elif issubclass(typ, np.floating):
        return float
    elif issubclass(typ, np.complex):
        return complex
    elif issubclass(typ, np.bytes_):
        return bytes
    else:
        return str
```

Note that `int('1.0')` gives an error, but `int(float('1.0'))` works.  So this more complex converter is less likely to choke on formatting details.